# supporting recursive relationships in xsd with sql annotation

Tags: xml, xsd, bulk-load

I have the following xsd and I cannot figure out why it has an error `"Namespace is not available to be referenced in this schema"` on `"element"` and how to fix it:

```
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">

  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:appinfo>
      <sql:relationship name="PlayerPlayer"
      parent="xmlTest"
      parent-key="PlayerID"
      child="xmlTest"
      child-key="ParentID" />
    </xsd:appinfo>
  </xsd:annotation>



    <xsd:element name="team">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="player" type="playerType" 
           maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>


  <xsd:complexType name="playerType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="playerID" type="xsd:ID"/>
      <xsd:element name="playerName" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="playerCap" type="playerType" 
        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

When I remove the  `type="playerType"` there is no error. But I need it because I wan to support a recursive relationship. I also need sql because I need to Xml Bulk Load in the database.

here is a sample of XML in case you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<team xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='TestRecursive.xsd'>


  <player>
    <playerID>c1</playerID>
    <playerName>Tommy Jones</playerName>
    <playerCap>
        <playerID>c2</playerID>
        <playerName>Eddie Thomas</playerName>
        <playerCap>
            <playerID>c4</playerID>
            <playerName>Patrick O’Shea</playerName>
        </playerCap>
    </playerCap>
  </player>
</team>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `@targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` from your root `xsd:schema` element, and the error will go away.

The `@targetNamespace` indicates the XML namespace of the XML document instance governed by the XSD.  You almost certainly don't want your XML document to be in the XSD namespace.

Your sample XML, in fact, does not use namespaces, so you need no `@targetNamespace` at all. If you did want to use namespaces, your reference to `playerType` would have to be appropriately prefixed with a namespace prefix declared to match the value of `@targetNamespace`.

Note finally that the declaration of `xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema"` does not have anything to do with the error.